# DocumentDB protocol support for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Looked through all the Azure blog pages but couldn't find anything related to my question.

I know that DocumentDB can support MongoDB clients with the help of protocol support but you have to create the database with MongoDB protocol support. I wonder if a DocumentDB database that is created with MongoDB protocol support is still usable by pure DocumentDB clients? Does the database support both types of clients or only MongoDB clients?

Comment: Why not deploy one and test?

Comment: @evilSnobu Not enough time :( Thought anyone may know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled MongoDB protocol support, recently we enabled support to connect to it via both MongoDB and DocumentDB SDKs.  Please note that MongoDB protocol support is in preview mode and we will update this answer once MongoDB protocol support has GA'ed.